# How to change the expressions in terms of a specific variable?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a series of analytical equations:

```
Subscript[M, 0] == P (L - x); 
Subscript[\[Sigma], 0] == (Subscript[M, 0] y)/Subscript[I, 0];
y == h/2
Subscript[I, 0] == (b*h^3)/12;
```

I want to find the expression h in terms of x, Subscript[I, 0], Subscript[M, 0].

I tried Eliminate, Solve, but they do not work as expected.

Is there a way to find an expression in terms of another variable in a series equations?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Isn't the answer simply given by your third equation? That is, $$h=2y$$

Comment: Sorry, my fault.
I want to eliminate y.
The final form should be:

    h(x)=Sqrt[(6P(L-x))/(b\[CenterDot]Subscript[\[Sigma], 0])]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve fails, because with so many extra variables there is no unique solution for `h`.  Try solving for more of the variables at once.

```
m == P (L - x)
σ == (m y)/i
y == h/2 
i == (b*h^3)/12

Solve[{m == P (L - x), σ == (m y)/i, y == h/2, i == (b h^3)/12}, {h, y, m, i}]

(* {{h -> -((Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[L*P - P*x])/(Sqrt[b]*Sqrt[σ])), 
     y -> -((Sqrt[3/2]*Sqrt[P*(L - x)])/(Sqrt[b]*Sqrt[σ])), m -> P*(L - x), 
     i -> (-((Sqrt[6]*L*P*Sqrt[P*(L - x)])/(Sqrt[b]*Sqrt[σ])) + 
    (Sqrt[6]*P*Sqrt[P*(L - x)]*x)/(Sqrt[b]*Sqrt[σ]))/(2*σ)}} *)
```

Note that I have eliminated the subscripts for clarity.

You also can use `Reduce`, although in this case it gives many not useful solutions (eliminated below) in addition to the desired ones:

```
Reduce[{m == P (L - x), σ == (m y)/i, y == h/2, i == (b h^3)/12}, {h, y, m, i}][[2, 2]]

(* h == -((Sqrt[6] Sqrt[L P - P x])/(Sqrt[b] Sqrt[σ])) || 
   h == (Sqrt[6] Sqrt[L P - P x])/(Sqrt[b] Sqrt[σ]) *)
```

Comment: @X.Arthur  Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot vote now because I do not have enough reputation.